# How to parse the string (date value in the given scenario) after the <br/> tag using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Currently, I'm trying to scrape web content using Python, BeautifulSoup.

after 1st block of code execution, got the below result -

```
<div class="some class name">
    <div>
        <h3>Situation reports January 2020</h3>
        <p>
            <a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200802-covid-19-sitrep-195.pdf?sfvrsn=5e5da0c5_2">
                <strong>Situation report - 1</strong>
            </a>
            <br>Coronavirus&nbsp;disease 2019 (COVID-19)&nbsp;
            <br>21 January 2020
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again after step 2 code execution, the result is as below,

```
<p>
    <a href="/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200121-sitrep-1-2019-ncov.pdf?sfvrsn=20a99c10_4" target="_blank">
        <strong>Situation report - 1</strong>
    </a>
    <br/>Novel Coronavirus (2019-nCoV)
    <br/>21 January 2020
</p>
```

I'm able to fetch each and everything except **21 January 2020** - which is after 
 tag.

the step 2 code is as below,

```
all_items = contentpage.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'sf-content-block content-block'})

rowarray_list = []

for items in all_items:
#    print(items, end='\n'*10)
    situation_report = items.find("h3")
    if situation_report is not None:
        situation_report = situation_report.text

        more_items = items.find_all('div')
        for single_item in more_items:
#            print(single_item, end='\n'*10)
            child_item = single_item.find_all('p')
#            print(single_item.getText(), end='\n'*2)
#            print(single_item.next_element, end='\n'*2)
            
            for child in child_item:
                print(child.next_sibling, end='\n'*2)
```

wrote the below code,

```
br_item = child.find_all('br')
for br in br_item:
    temp = br.next_sibling
    print(temp, end='\n'*2)
```

and got the output as,

[image]

**What I'm trying to do is to simply fetch only the date value. please help!**

Comment: Can u provide the details of url your trying to scrape.

Comment: @Sushanth https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for block in soup.select('p:has(>strong, >a)'):
    print(block.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[-1])
```

Prints:

```
2 August 2020
1 August 2020
31 July 2020
30 July 2020
29 July 2020
...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks.. it's working.. and the code is really clean..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need the last element inside every "p" tag. Try this:

```
for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'sf-content-block content-block'}):
    if i.find('p'):
        print(i.find('p').contents[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import requests

from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/situation-reports')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')



for div in soup.select('div.sf-content-block.content-block div p br + br'):
    text = div.find_next(text=True)
    print(text.strip())
```

prints:

```
2 August 2020
1 August 2020
31 July 2020
30 July 2020
29 July 2020
28 July 2020
27 July 2020
26 July 2020
25 July 2020
24 July 2020
23 July 2020
```

.. and so on........